# Difference between "theoretical computer science" and (beta) "computer science"

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Title says it all. From what I can see, "theoretical computer science" questions seem to be slightly more isolated to discussing algorithms, whereas "computer science" seems to have questions that are slightly broader and higher-level. Is there any place on the Stack Exchange sites where they give a longer description?

I'm just curious as to what niche the beta "computer science" site is meant to fill, as I see many topics in both forums that overlap.

Comment: This is what I hate the most about stackechange. SO is being split into separate parts. Hope it won't get the granularity of a tag.

Comment: Isn't "Computer Science" the same as "theoretical SO"?

Comment: There is also scicomp.SE (computational science)

Comment: @lukas "Hate" is a *very* strong word. Personally, I *love* that I needn't wade through Computer Science content when visiting SO.

Comment: @Manishearth, Comp. Sci. is actually quite a different field, it's more about the sciences supported by computing than the other way around.

Comment: @Bruno I know, just adding to the confusion ;-) . Also: "Comp. Sci. " is not that good an abbreviation choice :p

Comment: @AndrewBarber but solving "needn't wade through" problem causes other problems. Where should I post my question? Is it more CS or more about, say, Java? If I post it on SO how to get dudes form CS to view this? I'd love to be able to wade through CS, Code review, programmers content when I visiting SO. How to do so? All in all, tags system should be responsible for filtering, all CS related stuff should be on a one site. Peronally, I would add Master Tag that would does that: "Stackoverflow" "Programmers" etc.

Comment: I completely agree with @lukas. The fact that I have to come to meta Stack Exchange just to find out where I am allowed to ask a question about algorithms is ludicrous.

Comment: Jeff Atwood (SO co-founder), was at least partly responsible for the fragmentation of SO into arbitrary overlapping microsites that promoted identity politics and duplication/overlap, instead of attempting to reduce anti-patterns. He explained his reasoning c. 2010-2011. I disagreed with his reasoning then and I still disagree with it now. See these two discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) [2](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/unix-se-vs-serverfault-vs-superuser-vs-android-se).

Comment: @Bruno so Theoretical CS is 'Theoretical Theoretical SO' or 'Higher-Order Theoretical SO'...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The faq for both sites is always the best place to check with, in general.

[TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) spells out their requirement for discourse that might take place at the graduate level or higher.

> Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange is for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields. We welcome research-level questions in theoretical computer science (TCS).
>
> Although there is no black-and-white distinction between research-level questions and non-research-level questions, questions are considered to be "research-level" roughly when they can be discussed between two professors or between two graduate students working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and a typical undergraduate student. It does not include questions at the level of difficulty of typical undergraduate course/textbook homework/exercise.

Since Computer Science is still in Beta, it's faq is being worked on continually, but a basic draft can be found [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/7-essential-meta-questions-faq).

From one of the proposals ([Alex ten Brink](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/251/88)):

> Computer Science - Stack Exchange is for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science and related fields. If your question is about ...
>
> - understanding concepts of computer science
> - solving computer science problems
> - applying computer science to solve problems in other areas
> - issues unique to the discipline of computer science itself

In practicality, CS still has quite a bit of algorithm content, but less of a requirement for mathematical rigor (though having such doesn't disqualify a question), and more diversity in terms of applied questions (e.g., [Organisation and Architecture of Quantum Computers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/organisation-and-architecture-of-quantum-computers)).